# SQL Server database: Can't find an object which clearly exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

EDIT: How to give exec permissions to a user defined type?

Looks like "Bug2" is a user defined type.

```
select * from sys.types
where is_user_defined = 1 and name = 'Bug2'
```

Now to get rid of this error:

> "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'Bug2', database
>   'abc', schema 'dbo'"

What command should I be using?

---

I'm just playing around with someone else's code and bumped into this:

If I do

```
DECLARE @bugList Bug2

SELECT * 
FROM @bugList
```

Then I'm getting results

But if I do

```
SELECT * 
FROM Bug2
```

Then I get a

> Invalid object name 'Bug2'.

What is going on here?

Basically I'm trying to run a stored procedure which uses this "Bug2" and since there is some permission issue I'm getting this error on running it:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'Bug2', database 'abc', schema 'dbo'.

So all I want to do is:

```
GRANT EXEC ON Bug2 TO PUBLIC
```

But SQL Server is not able to find this object "Bug2" and therefore throws an error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: ,Bug2 what kind of type.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Got it working using this:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::Bug2 to PUBLIC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sys.types` use `sys.objects`. If `Bug2` is a table then query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name='Bug2' AND type='U'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [user-defined table type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx) (typically used for table-valued parameters). Look in db_nm > programmability > types > user-defined table types and you'll see a `bug2` object. You can address the permissions issue on that object (via script or GUI).

**Script Option:**

```
use [abc]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::[dbo].[bug2] TO [public]
```